# Is there a way to run XQuery in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, xpath, xquery

I want to retrieve data from currently displayed HTML page in Chrome browser.

For example: I want to get the number of columns of a table displayed in current page.

Is it possible to run XQuery from Chrome console, to get such information?

As we run XPath from console to get element references
example: `$x("//th")`.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but a quick google search pulled it up: [XQuery in the Browser](http://www.xqib.org/).

Answer (score 6):

XQuery is a superset of XPath, but currently there are no browsers with direct support for it. XPath is natively supported by current non-Microsoft browsers, but there are compatiblity layers like [Wicked Good XPath](https://github.com/google/wicked-good-xpath) which make it browser independent. Chrome which you do request *has* support for XPath, as you already realized.

If you want to run XQuery code in the browser, you might want to have a look at [XQIB (XQuery in the Browsers)](http://www.xqib.org/), but development has stalled some years ago.

The query you describe does not seem to require XQuery, plain XPath 1.0 should be fine, being something like

```
count(//table[@id='mytable']/tr[1]/th)
```